# How to synchronize an index in a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a vector `modbirths` which has 23 entries.

I have a vector `pop_vars_modded` which has 23 entries.

I want to synchronize my for loop so that `county[i]` and `pop_vars_modded[i]`
move at the same speed. For example, the loop would only do `county[1]` and `pop_vars_modded[1]`, ..... `county[19]` and `pop_vars_modded[19]`, but not `county[7]` and `pop_vars_modded[22]`, or other values that are not synchronous. Here is the code I am working with:

```
for(county in modbirths){
for( i in 1:23){
print(dbinom(county[i], pop_vars_modded[i], p=wyo2004_smokerate, log=T))
}}
```

the output gives me 23^2 = 529 numbers that `dbinom` produces (every combination of the 23 possible values `i` takes on), but I only want the key 23 ones.

Comment: for( i in 1:23){
print(dbinom(modbirths[i], pop_vars_modded[i], p=wyo2004_smokerate, log=T))
}

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I appreciate it. It all seems so simple now... the problem was not that the indexes needed to be synchronized, but that i created another variable that took on the 23 values as well.